# Django: Send form inputs in URL

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and was trying to create a web-app student management system in which students are added by admin and students can edit their details by entering their enrollment-id.

In models.py I added this model

```
class Student(models.Model):
  gender_choices = [('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female')]
  enrollment_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True, unique=True)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  father_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  mother_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  dob = models.DateField('date of birth')
  gender = models.CharField(choices=gender_choices,max_length=1,default=None)

  def __str__(self):
    return (self.first_name +" "+ self.last_name)
```

form for entering student enrollment id at index.html page is

```
  <form action="{% url 'students:detail' %}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="enrollmentid">Enrollment ID: </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="enrollmentid" placeholder="Enter enrollment id">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="dob">Date of Birth: </label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="dob" placeholder="Enter dob (YYYY-MM-DD)">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Edit Details</button>
  </form>
```

Now I want to go to `/students/detail/{enrollment id given by user}` route how can i pass the input to url

In views.py I have defined

```
def detail(request, student_id):
  try:
    student = Student.objects.get(pk=student_id)
  except Student.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("Student do not exist")
  return render(request, 'students/detail.html', {'student': student})
```

In urls.py I have defined

```
app_name = 'students'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('detail/<student_id>', views.detail, name='detail')
]
```

If i manually enter `http://localhost:8000/students/detail/ABC1235` then I successfully render the detail page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making a POST request, you should make a `GET` request, as this request is not modifying anything in your Database. Now, you can make the implementation like this:

```
 <form action="{% url 'students:detail' %}" method="GET">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="enrollmentid">Enrollment ID: </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="enrollmentid" placeholder="Enter enrollment id">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="dob">Date of Birth: </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dob" placeholder="Enter dob (YYYY-MM-DD)">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Edit Details</button>
  </form>
```

Then you can update your view like this:

```
def detail(request):
    try:
       student = Student.objects.get(pk=request.GET.get('enrollmentid'), dob=request.GET.get('dob'))
    except Student.DoesNotExist:
      raise Http404("Student do not exist")
    return render(request, 'students/detail.html', {'student': student})
```

Then on submitting the form, it will redirect to url like this: http://localhost:8000/students/detail/?enrollmentid=123&dob=2020-01-01